# Changing the permission for android facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app which was working fine till some time back. From past few days i am not able to get the notifications. i get a response saying permission is required. I wonder i was able to get the notifications earlier,if i didn't have the permissions. Is it that the facebook has changed their api. I am using the rest api for notifications.

Comment: please give us more info i.e., which notifications now younot gfet, which api you use,error code ....

Comment: @Ashwin with facebook what r u doing ,i mean simple wall post or image or videoo

Comment: @DanishIqbal: i am using Notifications.getlist api and i am getting this error code "{"error_code":200,"error_msg":"The \"manage_notifications\" permission is required in order to query the user's notifications."}
". Same api was working fine few days back.

Comment: @Samir i am trying fetch all the events for a user, along with his notifications. not a video or pic related operation.

Comment: which permission you add in facebook